# Setting up domain name for a different country

Tags: web-hosting, dns, server

I'd like to ask a question regarding domain registration and server details. We have an existing website in `.com` and we would like to have a `.jp` site for Japanese.

We have already registered the site in `.jp` (paid for one year). Our guy in Japan is asking these questions:

1. Update Nameservers
2. Domain Forwarding (JPRS Automated)
3. DNS Service (A/C Name/MX/TXT Records/Masked Forwarding)
4. NameServer Host Records (Private Nameservers)

Where can we get these? From the company that hosts our original site?

Answer (score 1):

These details are associated with your DNS provider. To make the site work you need to specify a DNS providers nameserver records to specify where the details for your site resolution are held. The other questions he is asking appear to be to do with if you want to use the registrar to host the DNS instead of a DNS provider of your choice. If your web host providers DNS hosting then you can provide your Japan contact the addresses for your DNS providers name server records.